# Работа с form + javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html5

```js
function addMsg() {
  
  let doc = document,
      msgName = doc.getElementById('name').value,
      msgDesc = doc.getElementById('desc').value,
      msgDate = doc.getElementById('date').value=new Date(),
      html = '<section class="msg"><div><span>By ' + msgName + '</span><span>' + msgDate +'</span></div> <p>'+ msgDesc +'</p></section>';
  doc.getElementById('result').innerHTML += html;
}
```

```css
section {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  width:320px;
  margin:3px;
}
p {
  border:1px solid #666;
  margin:3px;
  padding:5px;
  font-size:14px;
}
span {
  font-size:12px;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<aside class="right" id="result">
    <section class="msg"> 
      <div>
        <span> By Author </span>
        <span> 12:21 PM </span>          
        </div>
      <p>Много текста</p>        
      </section>
    <section class="msg">
      <div>
        <span> By Author </span>
        <span> 13:20 PM </span>
          
        </div>
      <p>Много текста</p>
        
      </section>
    <section class="msg">
      <div>
        <span> By Author </span>
        <span> 16:27 PM </span>
          
        </div>
      <p>Много текста</p>
        
      </section>
</aside>

<!-- form msg comm -->
<section class="form-box">
  <form action="">
<input id="name" value="" placeholder="Type your nickname here..." name="login" required>
  <textarea id="desc" placeholder="Write your comment here..." name="msg" required ></textarea>
<input id="date" type="hidden">
<input value="OK" type="submit" onclick="addMsg();">
  </form>
</section>
```

Добрый день!

Подскажите как доработать:
 1. Очистка полей после отправки
 2. Проверка полей на заполнение
 3. При отправке, обновляется и то что было отправлено пропадет, как сохранить, возможно можно сохранить в cookie
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function addMsg() {
  let doc = document,
    msgName, msgDesc, msgDate, html;

  if (document.getElementById('name').value) {
    msgName = document.getElementById('name').value;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('name').focus();
    return;
  }

  if (document.getElementById('desc').value) {
    msgDesc = document.getElementById('desc').value
  } else {
    document.getElementById('desc').focus();
    return;
  }

  msgDate = document.getElementById('date').value = new Date();

  html = '<section class="msg"><div><span>By ' + msgName + '</span><span>' + msgDate + '</span></div> <p>' + msgDesc + '</p></section>';

  if (document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += html) document.forms.myform.reset();
}
```

```css
input,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 320px;
  margin: 3px;
}

p {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

span {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<aside class="right" id="result">
</aside>
<!-- form msg comm -->
<section class="form-box">
  <form id="myform" action="">
    <input id="name" value="" placeholder="Type your nickname here..." name="login" required/>
    <textarea id="desc" placeholder="Write your comment here..." name="msg" required></textarea>
    <input id="date" type="hidden" />
    <input value="OK" type="button" onclick="addMsg()" />
    <!--type="submit"  по умолчанию отправляет форму, поэтому type="button"-->
  </form>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение к предыдущему ответу.
Если нужно проверять правильно ли ввел пользователь данные в соответствующие поля, то нужны регулярные еще выражения.
Реализовать можно разными способами. И HTML5 и JS.

Можно просто добавить атрибут `pattern=""`
Имя можно написать к примеру так "^[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z]+$"
Сообщение ограничить по минимальному и максимальному количеству символов  ".{5,50}"

Подсказка в данном случае корявая, но есть. В ней отобразится универсальное сообщение на языке системы пользователя и то что указать в атрибуте title=""

Для красоты нужен JS. Например вот для проверки простейших форм через `data-`.

`data-val` - регулярное выражение
`data-val-msg` - текст при неудачной валидации
`data-val-msg-id` - Id поля куда нужно вывести сообщение при неудачной валидации

```
<input class="inputs" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя" id="name" data-val="^[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z]+$" data-val-msg="Представьтесь"
      data-val-msg-id="nameMsg">
    <span id="nameMsg"></span>

<input class="inputs" type="text" name="msg" placeholder="Write your comment here..." id="desc" data-val=".{5,50}" data-val-msg="Введите сообщение от 5 до 50 символов"
      data-val-msg-id="descMsg">
    <span id="descMsg"></span>
```

JS

```
  // регистрация события загрузки документа
if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener("load", init, false);

// установка обработчиков для форм и элементов форм.
function init() {
for (var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++) {
var form = document.forms[i];

var formValidation = false;

for (var j = 0; j < form.elements.length; j++) {
  var e = form.elements[j];

  // пропускаем все что не поле ввода.
  if (e.type != "text") {
    continue;
  }

  // проверка имеются ли атрибуты требующие проверки.
  var pattern = e.getAttribute("data-val");

  if (pattern) {
    e.onchange = validateInput; // обработчик на изменение.
    formValidation = true; // форма требует проверку.
  }
}
 if (formValidation) {
  form.onsubmit = validateForm; // установка обработчика для формы на submit
   }
 }
 }

// обработчик на изменение содержимого полей ввода.
function validateInput() {
var pattern = this.dataset.val,
  valMsg = this.dataset.valMsg,
  valMsgId = this.dataset.valMsgId,
  value = this.value;

var res = value.search(pattern);
if (res == -1) {
   document.getElementById(valMsgId).innerHTML = valMsg;
   this.className = "error";
 } else {
    document.getElementById(valMsgId).innerHTML = "";
    this.className = "valid";
 }
 }
  var flag = false;
// обработчик на submit формы.
function validateForm() {

  var invalid = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < this.elements.length; ++i) {
    var e = this.elements[i];
    if (e.type == "text" && e.onchange != null) {
      e.onchange();
      if (e.className == "error") invalid = true;
  }
}

if (invalid) {
  return false;
  } else {
    flag = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Очистка полей после отправки делается очень просто, пример для name:

```
doc.getElementById('name').value = "";
```

Проверку полей на заполнение можно сделать либо в скрипте

```
if(doc.getElementById('name').value)
```

Либо через сам HTML (как мы видим вы это уже сделали), и она у вас уже работает

```
<input id="name" value="" placeholder="Type your nickname here..." name="login" required>
```

Сохранение проще и красивее всего сделать через localStorage

```
var data = {name:msgName, desc:msgDesc,date:msgDate };
localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data));
```

извлечение

```
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
```

Comment: если нажать кнопку "OK", идет отправка сообщения с пустыми полями, а уже потом показывает что мол вы не заполнили форму. Хотя должно изначально проверять, а уже после отправлять если есть инфо! 

Не пойму что не так сделал.
Попробую реализовать с помощью javascript.

Comment: @ntym а вы делайте не на кнопку `onClick` а на форму `onSubmit`

Comment: не смог разобраться с localStorage, есть примеры?

Comment: @ntym https://metanit.com/web/javascript/12.2.php

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addMsg() {
 let doc = document,
  msgName, 
  msgDesc, 
  msgDate, 
  html;
 if (doc.getElementById('name').value) {
  msgName = doc.getElementById('name').value;
 } else {
  doc.getElementById('name').focus();
  return;
 }
 if (doc.getElementById('desc').value) {
  msgDesc = doc.getElementById('desc').value
 } else {
  doc.getElementById('desc').focus();
  return;
 }
 msgDate = doc.getElementById('date').value = new Date();
 html = '<section class="msg"><div><span>By ' + msgName + '</span><span>' + msgDate + '</span></div> <p>' + msgDesc + '</p></section>';
 
 let test = {
  name: msgName, 
  desc: msgDesc,
  date: msgDate 
 }
 
 localStorage.setItem('test', JSON.stringify(test)); 
 
 //if (doc.getElementById('result').innerHTML += html) doc.forms.myform.reset();
 
 let testMSG = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("test"));
 
 if (doc.getElementById('testMSG').innerHTML += html) doc.forms.myform.reset();
}
```

```css
input,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 320px;
  margin: 3px;
}

p {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

span {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<aside class="right" id="testMSG">
</aside>

<!-- form msg comm -->
<section class="form-box">
  <form id="myform" action="">
    <input id="name" value="" placeholder="Type your nickname here..." name="login" >
    <textarea id="desc" placeholder="Write your comment here..." name="msg"></textarea>
    <input id="date" type="hidden" />
    <input value="OK" type="button" onclick="addMsg()" />    
  </form>
</section>
```

Подскажите где ошибка, не выводит историю из localStorage.

Заранее спасибо

Comment: надо отдельным вопросом писать